Specialize function by argument values known at compile time in C++
I have some function with 2 arguments: distance and radius
float expensive_function(float distance, float radius) {
    return distance + radius;
}


The whole project only uses 2 different radiuses and they both are known at compile time (1.2f and 3.4f). Is there a way to specialize this function knowing that? I would like something like that, but it doesn't compile:
template <float RADIUS>
float expensive_function(float distance) {
    return distance + RADIUS;
}

expensive_function<1.2f>(run_time_distance);
expensive_function<3.4f>(run_time_distance);


Compiler says:
Candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'RADIUS'
and
No matching function for call to 'expensive_function'
I'm not very familiar with C++ template programming, so I didn't expect it to work. I don't know if what I'm looking for even possible. I just want to make sure compiler will generate the most performant code for either cases, plus it's better semantically in my opinion.

Please explain what "it doesn't work" is.

the code you posted does not compile because of .... Why does the actual code not compile? We cannot know. Please post a [mcve]. The errors you show are not from the code you included

before C++20 you cannot have a floating type as a nttp

...and you need to actually use a float expensive_function<10.f>(run_time_distance);

if you only use 10 and 20 then just make it take int

Premature optimization. Templates won't gain computing speed there.

@AhmedAEK yeah, it's probably that. It does work with int. Unfortunately I have floats in real life

@3CxEZiVlQ why do you think so? I just it to perform as if it was two functions with different RADIUS arguments  hardcoded in. I know compiler can optimize it with dynamic arguments as well, but it's not guaranteed.

Before C++ 20 but after C++ 11, you can use std::ratio<20, 1>, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio#:~:text=The%20class%20template%20std%3A%3A,of%20type%20std%3A%3Aintmax_t.

Which compiler are you using? I tried gcc and got "error: 'float' is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter". I also tried clang, which was a bit more informative: "error: a non-type template parameter cannot have type 'float' before C++20". Which compiler accepts the template, only complaining when it's used? (Never skip the first error your compiler reports.)

before C++20 you cannot make a float or double Non-type template paramter.
you need to use int and some table to lookup to get it to compile
#include <iostream>

constexpr float floats[] = {1.2,3.4};
template <int index>
void foo()
{
    constexpr float value = floats[index];
    std::cout << value << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    foo<0>();
}

Demo
you can use an enum to make it easier to read
enum class float_values
{
    f1_2,
    f3_4
};

template <float_values index>
void foo()
{
    constexpr float value = floats[static_cast<int>(index)];
    std::cout << value << '\n';
}


Thank you! It's unfortunate I can't use floats to specialize directly. Lookup tables look hairy to me. This function is simple, but it's called millions of times per second, so I have to be sure it's compiled to the most simple code possible. I would probably just use two different functions with specialized names then :)

@simd If you're using this for optimization, you're doing things the wrong way. Constant folding and compile-time evaluation are already features of your compiler, and leveraging them has nothing to do with templates.

@simd value (and floats) is marked constexpr which effectively forces the compiler to compile it as if you had written float value = [the value] directly. The lookup table is purely compile-time.
